# Javascript issue with Dates

Tags: javascript, debugging, date

I am having some issues with javascript & using dates (in conjunction with the jQuery datepicker)

The code below gives me an error
date.getTime is not a function
endDate.setTime(date.getTime());

http://pastebin.com/Bgpw3QHF

Can anyone explain the problem?

Comment: `date` variable is defined anywhere? If not: this cause error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `date` by `endDate`. You've got a variable name mismatch.

```
endDate.setTime(date.getTime());   //current
endDate.setTime(endDate.getTime());//Should be
```

Comment: You think, that code endDate.setTime(endDate.getTime()) has any sense ? ;)

Comment: Only for development (testing) purposes. I'm not questioning his logic, I'm only fixing the code for him.